# How to add quotes to a string at notepad++ regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

Problem:

```
 11;05;12;201131201;4;RGBController;;Regal11_Anfang
```

I need it this way.

```
"11;05;12";201131201;4;RGBController;;Regal11_Anfang
```

At the first column i need ("")
Can anyone help me how to do this at notepad++ ?

Comment: If 11 is on the first column, why are you adding double quotes up to the 3rd column?

Comment: The problem is this string 11;05;12 is one colum.. so i need a double delimiter. that i get: "11;05;12"

Comment: Are all lines the same? Meaning the first 3 are actually on the same column?

Comment: Yes the first 3 are always at the same column.

Comment: Select Search Mode *Normal*. Find what: `11;05;12`. Replace with: `"11;05;12"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find what: `(\d+;\d+;\d+)`
- Replace with: `"\1"`
- Search mode: Regular Expression

[image]